# Why can’t the birthday problem be thought of like this

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is this problem in my text book. Now, they answer it

$$\frac{(365)!}{(365^n)(365-n)!}$$

That is, they used ordered sampling with replacement to obtain the sample space and ordered sampling without replacement to obtain the event that no two people share the same birthday.

But I thought about it in another way: I used unordered sampling with replacement $ {365+n-1 \choose n} $to obtain the sample space, and unordered sampling without replacement $ {365 \choose n} $ to obtain the particular event at hand.

Briefly, my line of thought was like this: let $x_1, x_2, ...x_{365}$ be the days people could be born on. We want the sum of these x’s (that is, the number of people born on day x) to be n, this is the sample space. For the event, let n of the x’s be 1 and the rest zero; thus we only want to compute the number of different arrangements of ones.

My answer and the one in the textbook are clearly different. I don’t understand why order matters in this question. Besides, shouldn’t it not matter whether I use ordered or unordered sampling because, put informally, the factors cancel out? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: @angryavian  ah yes sorry my mistake

Comment: Now i have hopefully put the correct formula (the book writes it in an expanded form, that’s why it confused me, apologies again)

Comment: "*But I thought about it another way: I used unordered sampling with replacement $\binom{365+n-1}{n}$ to obtain the sample space*"  While yes you can describe the sample space in this way, this is *not useful to do!*  We prefer sample spaces where outcomes are equally likely to occur.  The outcomes described in your alternate sample space are *not* equally likely to occur.  It is far more likely to have one of each of the 31 different birthdates in january represented than it is to have 31 people all born on january first, $31!$ times more likely in fact.

Comment: Remember that to use $Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$, you must be using a sample space where each outcome is equally likely to occur.  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery: you win or you lose.  You don't win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Comment: @JMoravitz ahaa yes! So that’s why the textbook has been emphasising “equally likely” so much! Thanks!

Comment: One final comment, you may appreciate the use of the $n\frac{k}{~}$ notation to represent the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) instead, $n\frac{k}{~}=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.  It cleans things up a good bit, making the probability in the birthday problem written instead as $\dfrac{365\frac{n}{~}}{365^n}$.  As with any notation however, make sure that your audience is familiar with your notation before using it.